# Homestead projects can't resolve other Homestead projects after update

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have been running a pretty old version of Homestead for years. At various times, I have tried updating a few times. I always got an error about being unable to resolve a package. Since the version of Homestead that I was running was technically working, I probably left my old version of Homestead running a bit longer than I should have.

I finally buckled down and worked through updating it. Everything appears to be back like it was except for one frustrating difference. Many of the projects in my Homestead interact with one another, oAuth, API integrations, etc., and while I can visit any project in my browser like before, none of the projects can resolve one another.

I always receive a curl error:
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host:

So, for example, one project that relies on an API call to another project for a dropdown list in a form, the API call never resolves and I can't populate the form.

Has anyone experienced anything similar? Any thoughts on what may be causing this? I have Googled around without much luck.

The problem initially started when I updated my laravel/homestead box. So, I thought that maybe the update corrupted the box somehow. I have run vagrant destroy and then vagrant add laravel/homestead to reinstall the newest version and the issue is still there. I noticed that the newest version that installs is 8.0.0-alpha2, so I tried specifying vagrant add --box-version 7.3.1 (the latest stable that doesn't have alpha or beta in the name) and again I am getting the same issue.

GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ConnectException
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: outside-project.local (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

If I make the exact same API call that the project is trying to make, it resolves as expected in Postman. I can also visit the project and all projects as expected in the browser.

If I make the exact same API call that the project is trying to make, it resolves as expected in Postman. I can also visit the project and all projects as expected in the browser. I would expect that projects can resolve each other just like they did before I tried updating Homestead.

Comment: I worked on this all weekend and then as soon as I resolve it like as soon as I post asking for help. If any one else is experiencing this, here is how I got it working:

vagrant ssh and add any projects that need to communicate with one another to the /etc/hosts file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one else is experiencing this, here is how I got it working:

vagrant ssh and add any projects that need to communicate with one another to the /etc/hosts file.